# How to save animation in mp4 format instead of avi?

Tags: export, animation

I'd like to save `Manipulate[]` output so that I can embed an mp4 in my pdf document (using the media9 latex package).  I've done this successfully in the past by manually constructing a table of Graphics objects, and then saving that to .avi format.  That .avi can then be converted to .mp4 by ffmpeg.

A cleaner way to do this is pointed out in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4229/export-animation-of-a-manipulate-autorun-sequence/4231#4231) but the .avi file that is generated causes ffmpeg to choke:

```
Output #0, mp4, to 'MyAutorun.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 412x345, q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 15 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> libx264)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as     bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I'm not really sure what this tool is complaining about, but wondered if there was a way to avoid using external tools to do this conversion and just export the animation data in mp4 format directly from Mathematica?

Comment: Couldn't you instead just export the `Manipulate` to  swf format? The media9 package can handle that. The predecessor movie15 did that nicely, too - see my [example page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/PDFmovie.html)

Comment: I suspect the encoder is complaining about the frame height being an odd number (345 pixels)

Comment: Simon, any idea how to make Mathematica use a non-odd numbered frame height?

Comment: Peeter, the exported avi has the same dimensions as the `Manipulate` object, so you could use the option `ImageMargins` in the `Manipulate`, but the simpler approach is probably to set the frame size in ffmpeg as shown in Jens' answer.

Comment: Jens showed below how to use the -s option of ffmpeg to work around the size issue.  I also tried adding ImageMargins -> 100 to my manipulate, but this didn't appear to force an even size to the generated Export[] output (and I still had to use ffmpeg -s)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edit 2**

Strictly speaking, the answer to the question "How to save animation in mp4 format" is simply this:

```
Export["MyAutorun3.mov", m, "VideoEncoding" -> "MPEG-4 Video"]
```

I'm adding this for completeness. The `.mov` file contains an `MPEG-4` encoded video, whereas the default with Mathematica is `Cinepak`. The reason why we have to jump through additional hoops is that this  output file doesn't appear to work with the flash-based video players that ship with `media9`.

**Edited: use Quicktime Player instead of ffmpeg**

On Mac OS X, there's an easier alternative to `ffmpeg` to create a movie that works with `media9`. It requires no additional software.

First use the [example from this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4229/export-animation-of-a-manipulate-autorun-sequence/4231#4231)

```
m=Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, -3, 3}], {a, 1, 10}, {b, -3, 3}]
```

Export as Quicktime, as F'x also suggested:

```
Export["MyAutorun.mov", m]
```

Open this movie in `Quicktime Player` (built-in on Mac) and choose `File > Export ...` with format `480p`. The newly created movie (let's call it `MyAutorun2.mov`) can be incorporated in your $\LaTeX$ file, as in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,height=170pt,
  addresource=MyAutorun2.mov,
  flashvars={%
src=MyAutorun2.mov
&scaleMode=stretch}
]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
\end{document}
```

You could also export the `Manipulate` as `SWF`,

```
Export["MyAutorun.swf", m]
```

Flash seems to do everything mp4 would do in your case: it's small and can be embedded in `PDF` for Adobe Reader using the `movie15` or `media9` packages.

To understand possible errors you may be seeing, I'll be more specific in describing what works for me:

Now create a $\TeX$ file with the contents

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=393pt,height=334pt
]{}{MyAutorun.swf}
\end{document}
```

The result displays and runs for me in Adobe Reader X 10.1.2 on Mac OS X Lion. I think `swf` is the easiest way to get movies from Mathematica to `PDF`. Everything else requires some detour.

The **disadvantage** of directly embedding Mathematica's `SWF` export into the `PDF` is that there are no *actually useable* playback controls. For that, the video player solution is needed. So here is how that works for me:

With an exported 'mov`, run the following:

```
ffmpeg -i MyAutorun.mov -s 540x360 -vcodec libx264 MyAutorun.mp4
```

What I added here is an explicitly even pair of numbers as the frame size, and the codec info. Hopefully, this will help prevent the errors you're seeing.

Finally, I embed the resulting `mp4` file with this $\LaTeX$ source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,height=170pt,
  addresource=MyAutoRun.mp4,
  flashvars={%
src=MyAutoRun.mp4
&scaleMode=stretch}
]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
\end{document}
```

I didn't worry about reproducing the aspect ratio of the movie correctly here. The main thing is of course that your `ffmpeg` sizes should be big enough to avoid a blurry image for the desired player width. This worked for me.

Comment: If I try .swf then viewer produces the following error in the pdf file when I try to view it:

"Argument Error - Invalid Parameter passed to method.

TypeError - Error #1009: Cannot access a property of method of a null object reference."

Note that I'm using StrobeMediaPlayer as recommended by the media9 maintainer:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45242/animations-with-movie15-and-swf-files

Using flv works better, but a second view attempt produces a "Buffering" status indicator that never goes away (I don't see that with an .mp4 format).

Comment: I added what works for me, using `SWF` directly because  with `mp4` you'd have to load a `SWF` video player anyway which then displays your movie, which seems convoluted when you have the choice to avoid `mp4` as your export format in Mathematica. But if you want to create `mp4`, another thing you could try is to export with `Export["MyAutorun001", m, "VideoFrames"]` and assemble the resulting `TIFF` files with the command `convert -quality 100 MyAutorun???.tiff myAutorun.mp4`. This requires `ImageMagick` (e.g. from MacPorts or Fink).

Comment: The `convert` utility also lets you rescale the frames (if it turns out odd pixel height is an issue for you).

Comment: the -s argument for ffmpeg works.  I'd tried -srch, -srcw, but looking at the ffmpeg help, I think those may be for something else.

Comment: Using your info, I've coded a small script to do this conversion, retrying if the size is odd:

https://github.com/peeterjoot/physicsplay/blob/master/bin/convertToMp4

Comment: Nice, it even tells people what LaTeX to use...

Comment: Not exactly.  It tells me what latex to use (since I'm probably the only one that will be using my personal movieFigure newcommand.  See:  https://github.com/peeterjoot/physicsplay/blob/master/notes/peeters_macros.tex )

Comment: I can dream, can't I? At least it would only be a small step to configure that last line to spit out a complete template...

Answer (score 6):

Exporting a QuickTime file (`.mov` extension) from Mathematica and then converting it into an MP4 file with ffmpeg does the trick for me:

```
Export["toto.mov", p];
Run["ffmpeg -i toto.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy toto.mp4"];
Run["rm toto.mov"];
```

It works with both ffmpeg version I have installed (an old CVS version dated sometime in 2004, and a CVS version dated 2009-04-12), and with Mathematica 8 on Mac OS X.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using.  If I try this I get an error:

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'twoCylindersFig3.mov':
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 583 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: cinepak (cvid / 0x64697663), yuv420p, 409x299, 581                                      kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc
...[mp4 @ 000000000036ED80] track 0: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container

Comment: @PeeterJoot Mathematic 8 on Mac OS X; edited my answer to include that

Answer (score 6):

The mp4 video to be generated must have even number of pixels in both dimensions. To ensure this independently from the input file, `ffmpeg` can be invoked as

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -vcodec libx264 -x264opts keyint=25 out.mp4
```

`-x264opts keyint=25` ensures that keyframes be inserted at every second. This is necessary for precise seeking within the video (using the <- / -> arrow keys of the keyboard [VPlayer.swf] or the slider [StrobeMediaPlayback.swf])

Comment: Thanks for detailing the magic required.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2020 and V12.1 the MP4 format is built in. The dedicated doc page has basic examples:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MP4.html

Quite a few options for export to consider:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not succeed in converting `.avi` into `.mp4` with `ffmpeg` as suggested by other answers, but a friend of mine directed me to [Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/). It is free and has very convenient and intuitively natural interface, so I converted my videos in few seconds without reading any manual. Unfortunately, it is not possible to pass options to Freemake Video Converter from command line in order to automate generation of `.mp4` files.