# How to Export this animation as a gif file for powerpoint presentation

Tags: export, animation

```
Animate[
  Manipulate[
   ParametricPlot[ Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /.
    Quiet @ NDSolve[
     {x'[t] == v[t],
     v'[t] == μ (1 - x[t]^2) v[t] - x[t] + A*Cos[ω*t],
     x[0] == xv0[[1]], v[0] == xv0[[2]]}, {x[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, tt}]],
    {t, 0, tt}, ImageSize -> {450, 450}, PlotRange -> 4, 
    AxesLabel -> {TraditionalForm[x[t]], TraditionalForm[v[t]]},
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[.5]
  ],
  {{μ, 0.75, "parameter μ"}, 0, 3, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{ω, 0.75, "parameter ω"}, 0, 3, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{A, 0.75, "parameter A"}, 0, 3, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{xv0, {1, 1}}, {-4, -4}, {4, 4}, Locator}], {tt, 0, 200}, 
  AnimationRate -> 3, AnimationRepetitions -> 3, AnimationRunning -> True
]
```

Comment: Not to answer your question (which you yourself should be able to work out with the online help of `Export` etc.), but I moved from GIF to MOV which works nicely as described here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4236/131. The quicktime movies have true color and integrate nicely into Powerpoint.

Comment: Yves Klett   The thing is, is that I have been working on this for awhile but the only thing it produces is a picture. Nothing moves.

Comment: Second argument of `Export` should be list of pictures. It is written in help.

Comment: Nothing is working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: This seems not a duplicate but there is an answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4727/5478

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85565/280

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to set values which are dynamic in `Manipulate`.

```
μ = .75; ω = .75; A = .075; xv0 = {1, 1};
```

Table pictures for different `tt`:

```
sol = Quiet@NDSolve[{x'[t] == v[t], v'[t] == μ (1 - x[t]^2) v[t] - x[t] + A*Cos[ω*t], 
                     x[0] == xv0[[1]], v[0] == xv0[[2]]
                    }, {x[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 20}];

dat = Table[
            ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, tt}, 
                           PlotRange -> 4, AxesLabel -> {x[t], v[t]}]
            , {tt, .1, 20, .2}];
```

Create gif.

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
Export["gif.gif", dat]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include a slider by this method too where you can decide the speed of the animation? So other format needed too then. Any possibilities with Mathematica?

Comment: @Masi You can add DisplayDurations option: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29485/5478

Comment: But I want the user to decide real-time the speed of animation. So I think gif is not a choice.

Comment: @Masi you can save `Manipulate/Animate` as CDF. If not then it does not matter if you use gif or other movie extension, you need a player able to specify frames per second. (I hope I get your question)

Comment: Do You mean that you can have this kind of speed bar in the animation in Gif too? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27680783/54964

Answer (score 16):

You can capture the frames as you manually manipulate like this:

```
 frames = {}
 Animate[Manipulate[(AppendTo[frames, ParametricPlot[ ... ] ])[[-1]] .. ]  ]
```

disable dynamic updating when done, then

```
 Export["test.gif",frames]
```

[image]

warning this will quickly generate a large number of frames..

Answer (score 9):

You can adjust the step size by changing the increment in the `Table` and you can adjust the animation rate using "DisplayDurations", e.g. for the Table above.

```
Export["dat.gif",dat, "DisplayDurations"->Table[t,{Length[dat]}]]
```

where t is display duration in seconds (frame rate: 1/t). Other options for exporting are in the [GIF documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/GIF.html)

Answer (score 6):

I came across this very helpful video when perusing Wolfram's documentation:

[How to Import and Export animations video by WRI](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ImportAndExportAnimations.html)

Answer (score 3):

I did not take a deep look at your code,but since you are using animate command,I suppose that your code is producing an animation which you can export it as movie into your powerpoint slides.

```
Export["test.avi",%]
```

which produces an .avi movie in your document folder.

Comment: works for me, while .mov does not work. Takes a long time to finish though.