# Creating an animated GIF

Tags: manipulate, export, animation

I used [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) to create an animation. However, is there a way to set $a$ to a value (say in 1/4 steps, starting at zero), run through the range of $b$ values (say in 1/4 steps), then change $a$ to the next value and run through all the $b$ values and to display both values as the animation is running?

```
Animate[
  StreamPlot[{-x + a*y + x^2*y , b - x^2 - a*y }, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
    ImageSize -> Large], 
  {a, -5, 5}, 
  {b, -5, 5}]
```

I want to create a GIF image of the above. When I look at [*Create Animation*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateAnimations.html), is it saying that you have to pass a list of graphics and use [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) to export those as a GIF? Is there no way to use `Animate` directly to do this?

Comment: Related: [(31312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31312), [(123679)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123679)

Comment: or: [27202](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/5478)

Comment: @MichaelE2: What a horrible result using MantoGIF. The result has blackouts, is unsteady and is also 150 MB.

Comment: I haven't used `ManToGIF` very much; I have my own way.  In this case, I think changing `Animate` to `Table` gets you nearly there. Add your own increment to the iterators, and `Flatten` the result to give to `Export`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way creating the GIF-animation is `Export` of image list without any `Animate`. The `"DisplayDurations"->xx` option can set the time (xx seconds) of demonstration of each frame.