# Exporting as GIF

Tags: export, animation

I want to export a simple animation as GIF. I had a look at [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27202/how-to-export-this-animation-as-a-gif-file-for-powerpoint-presentation) but could not understand what was being described. Any help would be appreciated.

For instance, how do I export the following animation as an GIF.

```
u[x_, t_] = -(1/2) Cos[x - t]^2 + 1;

Animate[Plot[u[x, t],{x, -10, 10},PlotRange->{0, 1.5},PlotStyle->{Red, Thickness[0.005]}],{t, 0, 10, 0.02}]
```

Thanks, Radz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply replace `Animate` with `Table` and store the result in a variable. I also edited your time range and suppressed the result with a semi-colon.

```
u[x_, t_] = -(1/2) Cos[x - t]^2 + 1;
pics = Table[Plot[u[x, t], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.005]}], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/50}];
```

Now, `Export`:

```
Export["anim.gif", pics]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Mark McClure, Thanks. I figured that out just a few minutes ago and was going to add it as a comment when I saw your answer:-). Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem - I'm glad you figured it out.