# Animating a 2D Plot as a 3D Plot

Tags: export, animation

This is a follow up question to the original question: [Original Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/exporting-as-gif/58372#58372)

The accepted solution (provided by @Mark McClure) can also be found in the original question. It is as follows.

```
u[x_, t_] = -(1/2) Cos[x - t]^2 + 1;
pics = Table[Plot[u[x, t], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.005]}], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/50}];
```

Then, export as follows:

```
Export["anim.gif", pics]
```

Is there a way of creating a 3D animation from the 2D animation? Something along the lines of the following: [Example](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolitonsFromTheKortewegDeVriesEquation/)

Thanks, Radz.

Comment: Dear @Kguler, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way of creating a 3D animation from the 2D animation?

You have misunderstood the whole thing. An animation is simply a series of images that are displayed after one another. If you want a 3D animation, make the frames in 3D. If you want 2D, make the frames in 2D.

```
u[x_, t_] = -(1/2) Cos[x - t]^2 + 1;
frames = Table[Plot3D[u[x, t], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -5, 5}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/50}];
Export["3danimation.gif", frames]
```

[image: 3D animation]

Comment: Dear @Pickett, Thank you.