# Animation, gif, ppt

Tags: graphics, animation

How can I save these animations as gif? I need reeeally quick answer if possible: :D
[image]

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/5478

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: One way to attack this problem is to look up [GIF](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GIF.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Please let us know if the link given by @Kuba doesn't work for you. Otherwise, the question will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Saved as a movie in mov format:

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];

Figure1[c_] := Plot[c + Log[2, x], {x, -2, 2}];
{a, b} = {2, 3};

m1 = Manipulate[
   Show[Figure1[c], PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-b, b}}],
   {c, -1, 3, .0001}
   ];

Export["movie.mov", m1];

Figure2[c_] := Plot[c + Log[2, x + c], {x, -3, 3}];
{a, b} = {3, 3};

m2 = Manipulate[
   Show[Figure2[c], PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-b, b}}],
   {c, -1, 3, .0001}
   ];

Export["movie2.mov", m2];
```