# Export animation from mathematica

Tags: graphics, animation, rasterize

I am trying to export an animation, but got an error..
The code is very simple, the combine function is a little complex:

```
Export["combin.gif", combine]
```

Here is the error message:

```
Rasterize::bigraster: Not enough memory available to rasterize Manipulate expression.
```

If try export a swf file

```
Export["combin.swf", combine]
```

The error message is

```
Export::rasterr: An unrecoverable error was encountered when rasterizing. >>
```

Hoe could I export an animation from mathematic?

Comment: What if you export frame by frame and use an external program to combine them into one animation?

Comment: Maybe doing it by yourself will work better? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/5478