# Problem with export gif

Tags: plotting, export, gif-format

As never before trial, I wrote the following code:

```
frames = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, a}], {a, .1, 6, .2}];

Export["trial.gif", frames]
```

but the result is obviously not the expected one.

How to fix?

I have tried searching the forum but did not succeeded.

I hope in your kind help.

Thank you!

Comment: You can add these options to your `ParametricPlot3D` command `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 6}}, SphericalRegion -> True`

Comment: There has got to be an existing Q&A about using a fixed `PlotRange` for this kind of thing, and I would prefer to mark this question as a duplicate rather than *easily found in the documentation.*  Would someone kindly help me locate a suitable original?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123793/2079