# Exporting Manipulate objects as .mov without UI controls

Tags: graphics, manipulate, export, animation

For a video project I am using Mathematica to create graphic mathematical visuals. However, I can't quite find the necessary setting in order to get a good looking image. I am using `Manipulate` in order to animate the plots, and exporting them as .mov files using `Export`. When I do this, the `Manipulate` UI is visible in the video file, which looks ugly. I want to be able to get just the actual graphic image itself. Is there a way to do this?

An example of my code for reference:

```
simplestring[x_, t_, n_] := Sin[x*n*Pi]*Sin[5*t]*Exp[-t]
complexstring[x_, t_] = 0.1 Sum[simplestring[x, t, n], {n, 1, 5}]
Export["complexstring.mov", 
  Manipulate[
    Plot[complexstring[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, 
      PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
      Background -> Black, 
      AxesStyle -> Gray, 
      ImageSize -> {1200, 920}], 
    {t, 0, 5}]]
```

Edit: [This post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/5478) contained the technique I needed. Credit to Kuba.

Comment: closely related: [How to Export this animation as a gif](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/5478)

Comment: Your example is incomplete because you don't give the definition of `simplestring`.

Comment: @m_goldberg thanks, included that in my post for completeness

Comment: @Kuba This worked! Thank you so much