# How to export quicktime video as h.264?

Tags: export, video

I am trying to export sequences of images as quicktime movies. The dafault codec (cinepak) produces low quality and large file sizes. There is little documentation of the other codecs, which can be viewed at:

```
Internal`$VideoEncodings // TableForm
```

I would like to export to H.264 but that does not seem to be available. My best results are to export with

```
"VideoEncoding" -> "TIFF"
```

(which produces a very large file)
and then open the file with quicktime player under OSX Mavericks, which automatically converts to H.264.
Any better solutions?

Comment: H.264 encoding requires buying a licence, that's probably the reason it's not included in Mathematica.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46813/57).

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4236/131