# CurveGraphics for 3D System of DEQs

Tags: graphics3d

I am using the [*CurveGraphics6*](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~gianluca.gorni/Mma/Mma.html#CurvesGraphics) NB to try and do some 3D related phase portraits and graphics.

The following works and produces an animation.

```
pic = NDSolve[( {
   {x'[t] == 2 y[t] (z[t] + 1)},
   {y'[t] == -x[t] (z[t] + 1)},
   {z'[t] == -(z[t])^3},
   {x[0] == z[0] == 0},
   {y[0] == 1}} ), 
   {x, y, z}, {t, -9, 9}, Animate -> True, PlotPoints -> 600, 
 ImageSize -> 300, HeadLength3D -> 1/30, DefaultDuration -> 40] // Last
```

I then attempt:

```
  Export["temp.gif", pic]
```

It exports the gif, but not the animation. What am I doing wrong?

I also welcome if anyone has ideas on how to better show this in 3D.

I do not see how to use the nice 3D Phase Portrait on the system above and maybe someone will be kind enough to provide guidance (as that is what I was really after).

Comment: Is there an animation? I don't see anything moving... In any case, that's probably unrelated to your question. In order to export an animation as gif, you should export a list of frames, not a single dynamic image.

Comment: But wouldn't it be really nice if *Mathematica* did allow direct export of a `Manipulate` or `Animate` to an animated gif, at least if it had a single control variable that varied discretely?

Comment: @rm-rf: You should see a point circling around the portrait. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @murray: Agreed. It would be great to have export what you see. If is has an animation or even variable parameters, and a single export to gif could capture it. Regards

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Sorry about that :)

Comment: @murray and OP: take a look here http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994;jsessionid=F81DC17EA304180AFB319A45B4E93E9A.wlp1?p_p_auth=83wbyBRj

Comment: @belisarius: Thank you, I will give that a go! Regards

Comment: Or here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4231/193 (by the same author, but you can upvote him there :)

Comment: @belisarius: Oh! I had missed your cited post, and I never knew that one can in fact directly export a `Manipulate` to an independent animation -- provided you use, say, `.mov` or `.avi` format rather than `.gif`.

Comment: But here http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994;jsessionid=F81DC17EA304180AFB319A45B4E93E9A.wlp1?p_p_auth=83wbyBRj you have the way for going from `.mov or .avi` to animated `.gif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't export this in the same way you might a *Mathematica* animation - the "animation" you see is a `Dynamic` object, updated via `Clock`. This is why the documentation for the package says you need *Mathematica* to use the new features, *Player* to just see them in action.

If you want to generate an animated GIF, you'll need to parse out the various objects in the generated "animation", and turn them into a list of the base plot and the "animated" point, which you can then use to export to a GIF.