# Manipulate Slider Value on the Plot

Tags: graphics, manipulate, export, dynamic, animation

Lets say I have a very simple manipulate in Mathematica given by:

`Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x],{x,-2 Pi,2 Pi}],{a,0,5}]`

I want two things which I am unable to do:

1. I want an animation of the following plot with `a` being displayed on the plot like `a = 'value'`
2. I want to export only the animation with the value of `a` displayed on it as a movie file. I do not want the slider or anything.

Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"a=", a}]], {a, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For exporting, there are many posts on exporting Manipulate to animations/movies. Please see this for example

[Export animation of a Manipulate autorun sequence?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4229/export-animation-of-a-manipulate-autorun-sequence)

If the above still does not answer you, then you can follow up.

ps. You can always just export like this (no need for manipulate)

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
tbl = Table[ Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"a=", a}]], {a, 0, 5, .1}];
Export["movie.mov", tbl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You beat me by seconds. My take: `Manipulate[ Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Epilog -> Inset[Framed[Style["a =" <> ToString[a], 20], Background -> LightYellow], {Right, Bottom}, {Right, Bottom}]], {a, 0, 5}]`

Comment: @Hector Your plot likes nicer with use of Inset.

Comment: @Nasser and Hector Thanks for your help. This solves my problem!!