# Making animations with Mathematica

Tags: animation, simulation

I want to export an animation for polar plot $r=\cos 2\theta$, instead of directly using Animate. But I want a table of snapshots: movie = ParallelTable[...] and a point that produce its animations like to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/making-mathematical-animations-with-mathematica). Then export it to my favorite animated graphics format, e.g.: Export["rose,gif", movie]. How can I do it?

I want a gif like this, merely with red point and without the circle and blue line of course for $r=\cos 2\theta$.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! You got most steps already covered. What is the actual problem?

Comment: You can export to animated gif directly from Manipulate. No need to make  `ParalleTable[...]`. And why the Parallel part? Here is a link http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994

Comment: I know it generally but I do not know details so I could not make it.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: @belisarius has given an answer for this question, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: @bobthechemist [this one?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6065/193)

Answer (score 5):

Using [ManToGif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFTjg.gif)  by Vitaliy Kaurov

```
ManToGif[man_, name_String, step_Integer] := 
  Export[name <> ".gif", 
   Import[Export[name <> Which[$OperatingSystem == "MacOSX", ".mov", 
     $OperatingSystem == "Windows", ".avi"], man], 
          "ImageList"][[1 ;; -1 ;; step]]];
```

Now write

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
r = 1;
backgroundAxes = Plot[0, {x, -Pi, 5 Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-r/2, 2 r + .5}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   Axes -> {True, False}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 4 Pi, Pi], None}];
t = Animate[Show[{backgroundAxes, 
     ListPlot[Table[{x - Sin[x], 1 - Cos[x]}, {x, 0, t, .1}], Joined -> True],
     Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{t - Sin[t], 1 - Cos[t]}]}],
     Graphics[Circle[{t, 1}, r]]}], {t, 0, 4 Pi}
   ];
ManToGif[t, "my_animation", 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Load it into the browser to play:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Nasser. Please look at My new edition of question.

Comment: @bigli Updated for your new version

Comment: A gif for polar plot $r=\cos 2 \theta$ like your update.