# What is required to remove a Part::pspec error? (Ver.9)

Tags: warning-messages

I asked a similar question here the other day, but I could not make myself clear. Then I ask once again.

I wanted to visualize a noise model on CCD sensors by *Mathematica* (Mine is ver.9). The following was what I executed:

```
noise := RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[10], {20, 20}];
plotnoise = DiscretePlot3D[noise[[i, j]], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

I got an error message besides the expected plot: `Part::pspec`.

**What does the error message mean?

How can I circumvent the error?**

Furthermore, I'm thinking to use `Manipulate` to simulate the effect of stacking of a lot of noise frames and embed it on my web page by use of Wolfram CDF:

```
noisemean[n_Integer] := Total[Table[noise, {n}]]/n;
noisestack = Manipulate[DiscretePlot3D[noisemean[m][[i, j]], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}, ExtentSize -> Full], {m, 1, 256, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

So, definitely I want to remove the error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error in MMA 10.4.0. This is my result when I run the first portion of your code: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vd3Dx.png). Can you check that the attributes of `DiscretePlot3D` in your version of `Mathematica` include a Hold attribute? I.e. report on the result of evaluating: `Attributes[DiscretePlot3D]`.

Comment: @MarcoB The result was `{Protected, ReadProtected}`. What does it mean? I'm a beginner...sorry

Comment: @TaikiBessho - are you using version 9?  I can reproduce the error in v9 but not v10

Comment: @JasonB Yes, I'm using ver.9. Is there any idea to circumvent this error on ver.9?

Comment: I have a workaround, but I wanted to check why you define your `noise` with a `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`?  Every time you call for a value `noise[[i,j]]`, it builds up 400 random numbers only to use one of them.

Comment: @JasonB Actually, for the first portion of my code, just set`=` is better. However, for the 2nd portion of my code, it has to sum up every different noise frames each time. For the purpose, I used SetDelayed`:=` instead of Set`=`. Maybe not smart way...

Comment: @MarcoB - If I run `Attributes[DiscretePlot3D]` from a session where I haven't run `DiscretePlot3D`, then it returns the 2-element list that Taiki wrote above.  But if I ask for the attributes after running a `DiscretePlot3D` example, then it gives me the `HoldAll` as well.  I get this in version 9 and 10

Comment: @JasonB I see. It would seem that the first execution triggers the loading of some code behind-the-scenes. That's interesting on its own, but maybe not relevant to Taiki's problem. Thanks for checking anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is similar to the problem you get when you try to use an interpolating function inside a numeric integral, and the solution is [similar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86631/9490):  Define a helper function that only calls `Part` when the arguments are both integers:

```
noise := RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[10], {20, 20}];
noisefunc[i_Integer, j_Integer] := noise[[i, j]];
DiscretePlot3D[noisefunc[i, j], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}, 
 ExtentSize -> Full]
```

and it works without issue.

I do need to point out that, the way you've written this code, it generates 400 random numbers for every plotted data point.  So you are generating $400^2$ random values and only plotting 400 of them.  You could either define `noise = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[10], {20, 20}]` instead, or set it up like

```
DiscretePlot3D[
 RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[10]], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}, 
 ExtentSize -> Full]
```

and get the exact same plot.

For the `Manipulate`, I would do something like this:

```
Manipulate[
 DiscretePlot3D[
  Mean@
   RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[10], m],
  {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}, ExtentSize -> Full], {m, 1, 256, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: One more question, how did you export the gif image? Did you use `Animate`? I tried with `Animate` but it was not smooth like yours.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66986/9490