# Manipulate to GIF

Tags: manipulate, export

I am using the following example code to export `Manipulate` to `GIF`:

```
ManToGif[man_, name_String, step_Integer] := 
 Export[name <> ".gif", 
  Import[Export["f:\\test.avi", man], "ImageList"][[1 ;; -1 ;; step]]]

man = Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, end}], {end, Pi, 2 Pi, 0.1}];

ManToGif[man, "f:\\test", 1];
```

Is there another possibility to do that? **How can I see the value of the variable `end`?**

You see at bottom of the movie some strange black bars and also at the right edge a black vertical line, which should not be there.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you press that `+` toggler to open the additional control bar? It includes `InputField` which shows how the value updates.

Comment: Or, programmatically, `{end, Pi, 2 Pi, 0.1, Appearance -> "Open"}`.

Comment: Those are not "strange black bars", those are the background. If you want to avoid showing the background you need to control the size of the plot so that it covers the same area at all time.

Comment: closely related: [How to Export this animation as a gif file](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/5478)

Comment: @Kuba and @C. E: Thank you. This is nearly the solution `Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, end}, PlotRange -> {{0, end}, {-2, 2}}, 
   ImageSize -> 500], {end, Pi, 2 Pi, 0.1, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
  ContentSize -> 550]`. But the vertical extension of the surrounding frame (in vertical direction) of the `Manipulate` box is still not constant ... what should I do?

Comment: @JasonB: So this is not the case in my comment above. When I use e.g. `PlotRange -> {{0, 2Pi}, {-2, 2}}`then everything is fine

Comment: @mrz - I still got a bit of movement in the axes until I added the option `ImagePadding -> 10`, now I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c56Ca.gif).  Another option would be to give `ImageSize` two numbers, so that the width and height are always specified.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this outside of the manipulate box and show the variable's value as a legend. Also by using fixed image sizes and aspect ratios you can minimize the occurrence of black bars as the variables change.

**First Step:**
    Make a table of your desired Plots, I think the code here is relatively easy to understand:

```
Anim = Table[
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, t}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.1, ImageSize -> 500, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotLegends -> TextString@Row@{"T=", t}]
   , {t, Pi, 2 Pi, .1}
   ];
```

**Second Step:** Export it as a GIF image :)

```
Export["anim.gif", Anim]
```

**Final Result:**

[image]

Hope it's suitable for what you have in mind ;)

***UPDATE***

If you want it to move forward an then backward you can make tables of the animation for each direction and join them:

```
Anim1 = Table[
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, t}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.1, ImageSize -> 500, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotLegends -> TextString@Row@{"T=", t}]
   , {t, Pi, 2 Pi, .1}
   ];

Anim2 = Table[
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, t}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.1, ImageSize -> 500, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotLegends -> TextString@Row@{"T=", t}]
   , {t, 2 Pi, Pi, -.1}
   ];

Anim = Join[Anim1, Anim2];
```

[image]

***UPDATE 2***

If you want to do this with the manipulation box just add a two-dimensional picture size to your plot like this:

```
man = Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, end}, 
   ImageSize -> {500, 250}], {end, Pi, 2 Pi, 0.1, 
   Appearance -> "Open"}, ContentSize -> 550]
```

[image]

Or this one (without fixing the plot range):

```
man = Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, end}, ImageSize -> {500, 250}], {end, Pi, 2 Pi, 
   0.1, Appearance -> "Open"}, ContentSize -> 550]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can still use manipulate and get good results if you use the fixed formatting there

Comment: Thank you for your help ... this I did already, but I wanted to see the whole window of the `Manipulate` function - therefore my question.

Comment: would it be possible to get a complete example, with the exporting, the inclusion of the manipulate UI, and the alternating between forwards and backwards? I'm not super Mathematica savvy yet so it's taking me a while to figure out how to string to it together. basically my whole interest in Mathematica is being able to type in 3-D equations and get exactly this behavior

Comment: @JosephGarvin can you give an example of the 3D equation that you're interested in?

Comment: @SiavJosep: something like $z=\frac{ax}{ax+by}$ with sliders for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
ManToGif[man_, name_String, step_Integer] := 
 Export[name <> ".gif", 
  Import[Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test.avi"}], man], 
         "ImageList"][[1 ;; -1 ;; step]]];

man2 = Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, end}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}]
                 , {end, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];

ManToGif[man2, FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "test"}], 1];
```

This creates an AVI and corresponding GIF animation:

[image]

Comment: For the original `ManToGif`, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4229/export-animation-of-a-manipulate-autorun-sequence/4231#4231) by Vitaly and [its link](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994) to his community post. (The original is essentially the same as this, but with a fix for MacOS.)