# How to export and save animated graphics as video files to a specified folder location?

Tags: plotting

```
ai = Manipulate[
  Plot[A Sin[\[Omega] x + \[Phi]] + B, {x, -10, 10}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    "f(x)=" <> ToString[A] <> "sin(" <> ToString[\[Omega]] <> "x+" <> 
     ToString[\[Phi]] <> ")+" <> ToString[B], PlotRange -> {-6, 6}, 
   Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> 700], {{A, 1}, -2, 5, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Omega], 1}, -3, 8, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Phi], 0}, -\[Pi], 2 \[Pi], 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{B, 0}, -1, 5, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
Export["test.mp4", ai, "ControlAppearance" -> None] // SystemOpen
```

[image]

How to export and save the animated graphics generated by the above code in the form of video files to the specified folder location?

Comment: hello. There are few question/answers on this forum showing how to save Manipulate as animation and also to mp4. check [how-to-save-animation-in-mp4-format-instead-of-avi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4232/how-to-save-animation-in-mp4-format-instead-of-avi) and check [manipulate-to-gif](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123679/manipulate-to-gif)

Comment: Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "test1.mp4"], ai, 
 "ControlAppearance" -> None, "FrameRate" -> 2, 
 "AnimationDuration" -> 50]